# Flutter Radio List

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

i have radio list in flutter on different sheet i called the function of radio list on my home screen and i want if i click on the radio list it will navigate to my edit screen i had used inkwell function but it is still not working what should i do now

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/Edit_Screen.dart';

class RadioListExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RadioListExampleState createState() => _RadioListExampleState();
}

class _RadioListExampleState extends State<RadioListExample> {
  int _selectedValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const EditScreen()),
        );
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          RadioListTile(
            title: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Heading',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Text(
                  'This is my subheading for test',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Today 06:00 PM',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            value: 1,
            groupValue: _selectedValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedValue = value as int;
              });
            },
            secondary: Icon(
              Icons.star,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I had tried inkwell function on tap but it is not working

Comment: Any errors? Did the radios update properly? Provide more information on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening cause the RadioListTile widget also tap-able, it generally calls the onChanged function of it's click.
You need to think of some other way to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add toggleable to true in RadioListTile and add an event in onChange.

```
RadioListTile(
  value: controller.listItem[index],
  groupValue: controller.selectedFolder.value,
  toggleable: true, // Enable toggleable
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    // Your function here
  },
  title: Text(controller.listItem[index],),
)
```